# Playscape Analytics : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

I'm having some problems with Playscape Analytics. When I try to report level start, I get the error below:

```
 I/Unity   ( 6366): NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 I/Unity   ( 6366):   at Playscape.Analytics.Report.ReportLevelStarted (System.String level, IDictionary`2 additionalParams) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 I/Unity   ( 6366):   at GreenroomScript.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Here is the line of code I am using:

```
Report.Instance.ReportLevelStarted(AppHelper.sharedHelper().missionManager.m_activeMissionSet.ToString(), null);
```

`AppHelper.sharedHelper().missionManager.m_activeMissionSet.ToString();` is printing the string.

Anyone have any ideas of what the problem is?

Comment: There's just a line of comment, there...maybe you forgot to paste the entire code? Because it's impossible to help, looking at just the error.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the last part.. Ty Andrea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
public void ReportLevelStarted(string level, IDictionary<string, double> additionalParams)
```

method `additionalParams` can not be `null`. Instead of `null` pass an empty dictionary.